# Auto Re-Image Primary Drive

Tags: windows-7

Scenario...
I am running Windows 7 (64Bit) and have created an image of my C: Drive and the image (WindowsImageBackup) is stored on my D: drive - What I want to do is to be able to click on a shortcut that will re-start my PC and automatically restore the WindowsImageBackup image to the C: Drive with no further user input.

Research...
I have Googled many times for an answer to this to no avail. I have experimented with BCD Boot, ReAgent.exe, boottore, UnAttend.xml, and various other re-imaging options but none have answered my query.

Question...
Can this be done without using third party software such as Ghost,Clonezilla, R-Driveimage, DriveimageXML?

At the moment I use reagentc /boottore followed by the shutdown command to reboot the PC into the recovery environment which opens a dialog that requires user input to continue - I would like to automate user input process or discover if there is any switches or DOS commands that can give me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This method is not completed.

This is possible using linux. At first you should clean all unused disk space. Good idea is defragment partition before. You should clean unused space using many available programs for free use eraser.  boot any LIVE linux distro. make compressed copy using command 'dd if=/partiotnion/where/it/is|gzip >/partition/image.img.gz

next you must prepare linux distro. this should boot, do reverse above - unpack image to the partition device and reboot. It's not easy to prepare.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the suggestion.. Unfortunately I know virtually nothing about Linux or even how I would integrate it in a Windows 7 environment, or even if it can be integrated into W7 - I was hoping for simplistic suggestion with what I already have.. but cheers for trying

Comment: You can try install linux for another partition. Receipt is here: http://www.howtoforge.com/dualbooting-windows-7-and-linux-mint-12 and on many places. You can linux partition for windows backup storage. In this scenario you should modify boot sequence for auto recovery. Usually you use dd & gzip commands and bash for this making recovery script. Be careful what device do you use :) Try make this on any test drive if you have one. About linux, you do not need install graphics environment. This only consumes space and time in your needs.